# Characteristic function of non-central $\chi^2$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, characteristic-functions

Consider $X_1,\ldots, X_n$ iid random variables with $X_1\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, some real numbers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$.

Define $Z:=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i+\alpha_i)^2$ and $\kappa:=\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i^2$

I want to show by direct integration, that

$$E[e^{uZ}]=\frac{\exp({\frac{\kappa u}{1-2u}})}{(1-2u)^\frac{\kappa}{2}}$$

for any $u\in\mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(u)\le 0$. What I have done so far is the following:
$$
\begin{align}
E[e^{uZ}]&=E[e^{u\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i+\alpha_i)^2}]\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^nE[e^{u (X_i+\alpha_i)^2}]\text{, since }X_i\text{ are independent}\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{u (x+\alpha_i)^2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx\text{, since }X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(2u-1) (\frac{x+\alpha_i}{\sqrt{2}})^2}e^{x\alpha_i+\frac{1}{2}\alpha_i^2}dx\\
\end{align}
$$

The right hand side can be written as

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\exp({\frac{\kappa u}{1-2u}})}{(1-2u)^\frac{\kappa}{2}}&=\exp\Big({\frac{\kappa u}{1-2u}}-\frac{\kappa}{2}\ln(1-2u)\Big)\\
\end{align}
$$

How can I go on from here? Maybe I can apply some Fourier Inversion formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps this answer helps: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/168418/119261.

Comment: Thank you. This is very helpful! However, I'm still wondering if $\mu=\frac{2\alpha_i u}{1-2u}$ and $\sigma^2=(1-2u)^{-1}$ could be chosen, since these seem to be complex numbers.

Comment: Looks like there is something like a complex Normal distribution, but I'm not sure, if things just behave the same.